# Plotting two pandas series together one appears flat

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am practicing with Python Pandas plotting functions and I am trying to plot the content of two series extracted from the same dataframe into one plot.

When I plot the two series individually the result is correct. However, when I plot them together, the one that I plot as second appears flat in the picture.

Here is my code:

```
# dailyFlow and smooth are created in the same way from the same dataframe
dailyFlow = pd.Series(dataFrame...
smooth = pd.Series(dataFrame...

# lower the noise in the signal with standard deviation = 6
smooth = smooth.resample('D').sum().rolling(31, center=True, win_type='gaussian').sum(std=6)

dailyFlow.plot(style ='-b')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
    
smooth.plot(style ='-r')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
    
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
smooth.plot(style ='-r')
dailyFlow.plot(style ='-b')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

Here is the output of my function:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I already tried using the parameter `secondary_y=True` in the second plot, but then I lose the information on the second line in the legend and the scaling between the two plots is wrong.

Many sources on the Internet seem to suggest that plotting the two series like I am doing should be correct, but then why is the third plot incorrect?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For the data you have, the 3rd plot is correct. Look at the scale of the y axis on your two plots: one goes up to 70,000 and the other to 60,000,000.

I suspect what you actually want is a `.rolling(...).mean()` which should have a range comparable to your original data.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to make both plots bigger, you cold try something like this

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_ylim([0, 75000])
# plot first graph 

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2.set_ylim([0, 60000000])
#plot the second graph
```